# Clock Pulse is shifting in Tikz-timing?

Tags: tikz-timing

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary[dual arrows]{clockarrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
scale=2.5,
timing/slope=0.1,
timing/rowdist=3ex,
]
\textnormal{Clock} &  [black] {h} 47{c} \\ 
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.north west){\tiny +5V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.south west){\tiny 0};
\vertlines[help lines,red]{0,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

And output

[image]

The clock pulses are shifting. How can we do?

Comment: As Martin mentions in the manual, `scale` key won't scale things properly. He recommends scalebox or putting things inside a node. It seems a little awkward why he does that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thing like this:

[image]

TikZ-timing diagrams scale relative to the font size as stated in the package [documentation](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing/tikz-timing.pdf). Options for scaling, then, can be using a `\scalebox{<factor >}{<content>}` or putting things inside a node as mentioned in the documentation and also noted by @percusse in a comment. A more natural way, though, could be scaling like a normal text, that is, using standard sizes (`\small`, `\large`, `\Large`, ...etc) or issuing `\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}` command. Here, I used `\Huge` for example:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary[dual arrows]{clockarrows}
\begin{document}

{%
\Huge %\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont
\begin{tikztimingtable}[line width=.5pt,
timing/slope=0.1,
timing/rowdist=3ex,%
]
\textnormal{\small Clock} &  [black] {h} 47{c} \\ 
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.north west){\tiny +5V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.south west){\tiny 0};
\vertlines[help lines,red]{0,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is working, @AboAmmar.